# drill down on fuisonchart

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, fusioncharts

I created two php pages. the first is the main fusionchart that plots a pie chart for total output each for various factories. I have also included a like making the chart clickable. When clicked, it is meant to show a break down graph analysis that makes up the portion of the chart. But the drill down chart refuses to plot any diagram, but rather gives an empty chart string on the screen. I have placed the code for your analysis.

```
<?php
//We've included ../Includes/FusionCharts.php and ../Includes/DBConn.php, which contains
//functions to help us easily embed the charts and connect to a database.
include("/Includes/FusionCharts.php");
include("/Includes/DBConn.php");
//a file having a list of colors to be applied to each column (using     getFCColor() function)
include("/Includes/FC_Colors.php");
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> FusionCharts Free - Database and Drill-Down Example </TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" SRC="../../FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js">            </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY> 
<?php
//This page is invoked from Default.php. When the user clicks on a pie
//slice in Default.php, the factory Id is passed to this page. We need
//to get that factory id, get information from database and then show
//a detailed chart.

//First, get the factory Id
//Request the factory Id from Querystring
$factoryId = $_GET['factoryId'];

//Connect to database
$link = connectToDB();

//$strXML will be used to store the entire XML document generated
//Generate the chart element string
$strXML = "<chart caption='Factory Output' subCaption='By Quantity' pieSliceDepth='30' showBorder='1' showNames='1' formatNumberScale='0' numberSuffix=' Units' decimalPrecision='0'>";

//Now, we get the data for that factory
$strQuery = "select * from factory_output where factoryId=" . $factoryId;
$result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die(mysql_error());

//Iterate through each factory
if ($result) {
  while($ors = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     //Here, we convert date into a more readable form for set name.
     $strXML .="<set name='" . datePart("d",$ors['datePro']) . "/" . datePart("m",$ors['datePro']) . "' value='" . $ors['quantity'] . "' color='" . getFCColor() . "'/>"; 
  }
}
mysql_close($link);

//Close <chart> element
$strXML .="</chart>";

//Create the chart - Column 2D Chart with data from $strXML
echo renderChart("charts/FCF_Column3D.swf", "", $strXML, "FactoryDetailed", 600, 300);
?>
</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a `link` attribute to your dataset.

See **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025273/how-to-create-pie-chart-using-javascript/29284465#29284465)** answer to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can drill-down to descendant charts by simply clicking the data plot items on the parent chart. A descendant chart can either replace the parent chart with an option to drill-up, or it can open in a new window or frame.

```
"data": [{
    "label": "Apple",
    "value": "810000",
    "link": "newchart-xml-apple"
  }, {
    "label": "Cranberry",
    "value": "620000",
    "link": "newchart-xml-cranberry"
  }, {
    "label": "Grapes",
    "value": "350000",
    "link": "newchart-xml-grapes"
  }]
```

Check here demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/e01wx8ds/

To know more this feature refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/php/add-drill-down-using-php

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/drill-down