# How to create pie chart using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, charts, fusioncharts

I have created a pie chart using javascript and my data is stored in mongodb.
In my chart I am able to separate slices of pie chart.

That is whenever I roll on my mouse on any of the slices it is showing the data.

But my requirements are, that if I click any of the slice of it, it should display the data in some table.

This is my HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pie chart</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.zune.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
FusionCharts.ready(function(){
    var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
      type: "pie2d",
      renderAt: "chart-container",
      width: "450",
      height: "350",
      dataFormat: "json",
      dataSource: {
          "chart": {
              "caption": "Split of Visitors by Age Group",
              "subCaption": "Last year",
              "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#f2c500,#f45b00,#8e0000",
              "bgColor": "#ffffff",
              "showBorder": "0",
              "use3DLighting": "0",
              "showShadow": "0",
              "enableSmartLabels": "0",
              "startingAngle": "0",
              "showPercentValues": "1",
              "showPercentInTooltip": "0",
              "decimals": "1",
              "captionFontSize": "14",
              "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
              "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
              "toolTipColor": "#ffffff",
              "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
              "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
              "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
              "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
              "toolTipPadding": "5",
              "showHoverEffect":"1",
              "showLegend": "1",
              "legendBgColor": "#ffffff",
              "legendBorderAlpha": '0',
              "legendShadow": '0',
              "legendItemFontSize": '10',
              "legendItemFontColor": '#666666'
          },
          "data": [
              {
                  "label": "Teenage",
                  "value": "1250400"
              }, 
              {
                  "label": "Adult",
                  "value": "1463300"
              }, 
              {
                  "label": "Mid-age",
                  "value": "1050700"
              }, 
              {
                  "label": "Senior",
                  "value": "491000"
              }
          ]
      }
  });
    revenueChart.render("chart-container");
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've had great success with Google's Visualization API - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

Comment: You should include the code you use for hovering, so we can indicate how to change that so it no longer reacts on hovering and instead only reacts on clicking.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been asked years ago, but anyone who might bump into this can see it **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/pz5fz10k/)**.

You have to use `link` attribute, as seen [here](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/DrillDown/JavaScript.html).

```
               "link": "JavaScript:populate('411');",
```