# how to get the value of the pie slice in fusion chart

Tags: fusioncharts

I'm new to FusionCharts.
I have generated a pie chart with slice, my question is:

When I click on the slice in the pie chart, I need the label name of the slice.

How can I write the on click event and get the name of label?

Answer (score 0):

I don't much about charts and such, I'm fine using Word for this. But in 2D Graphics I've learned you can use

...contains(shape)
...intersects(shape)

To see if shapes are inside eachother (to contain) or if they overlap eachother (to intersect).

When adding a mouseListener, you can use

e.getX() and e.getY()

to get the current X and Y position of mouse on screen.

So something like

```
for (pieChartPieces p: piece)
{
    if (pieChartShape.contains(e.getX, e.getY))
    {
        //* Some kind of notifier for user pops up here.
    }
}
```

Comment: e.getX and e.getY are methods btw, so it's e.getX() and e.getY()

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6W97k/211/)

It uses "dataplotClick" event to retrieve the label of the pie slice.

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use events "dataplotClick" to get the value of the pie slice when plot is clicked

```
"events": {
  "dataplotClick": function(event, data) {
    alert(data.categoryLabel);
  }
}
```

To know more about it refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events#event-dataplotClick

Please refer Demo Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kumtbep7/1/

Answer (score -1):

You have to use link attribute, as seen [here](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/DrillDown/JavaScript.html).

`"link": "JavaScript:populate('411');",`

See the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pz5fz10k/).

Don't forget to implement the `populate()` with the whatever you need to do.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025273/how-to-create-pie-chart-using-javascript/29284465#29284465) to a similar question (with answer).